# how to make RSS feeds where the /rss/ is at the end of the URL, not at the beginning?

Tags: django, rss, django-rss

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/ describes the way to use the Feeds class, and it works well for me, but it requires the URL to be like http://example.com/rss/feedid/parameters/

I need it to be http://example.com/feedid/parameters/rss/

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Django's URLs are based on regexes, I think that you can use a rule like this:

```
(r'^(?P<url>.*)/rss/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),
```

Though personally, I have never used the Django syndication framework - I just use generic views (or wrappers around generic views) with the `content_type` option, and generate the RSS/Atom with a template.